# SQL Azure - Killing a Process

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I’m trying to kill a process in Azure and I’m getting this status message.
“SPID 55: transaction rollback in progress. Estimated rollback completion: 0%. Estimated time remaining: 0 seconds.”.

Apparently, there is a rollback on a table taken place and it’s been going on for 3 days now, it has over 13M records.

I tried renaming, deleting, dropping, truncating the table, but to no avail.

Is there anything else one can do, to resolve this issue?

Comment: Contact SQL Azure support

Answer (score 0):

wait for transaction to be completed
if you are willing to take a risk - you can delete the DB and restore to a specific point in time just before you executed the transaction that you killed.
regarding contacting azure support, i am afraid it will probably take more time then for the transaction to rollback

Answer (score 0):

Please contact support.  It's not clear from your description if you've hit an issue with out service.  The best way to resolve this is with a support ticket.  You can create a ticket directly in portal.azure.com.